# how to delete a folder using linux command line

Tags: bash

I am using Angular V2.

I setup a project using:

```
ng new PROJECT_NAME
cd PROJECT_NAME
ng serve
```

How do I delete the whole Angular project I setup via the command line (am on ubuntu).

Thanks

Comment: if you are asking how to remove a directory, the Q should go to super user. and I am 200% sure it is duplicated there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of a bash than an angular question.

```
cd ..
rm -fr PROJECT_NAME
```